# datatables warning method Illuminate\routing\route::getpath does not exist Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, datatable

Am working on laravel 6 datatable

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    // return $dataTable->render('admin.rooms.view');
    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('rooms_access'), 403);
    return view('admin.rooms.view');
}

public function roomsList()
{
    Log::info("ajax call......");
    /* $rooms = DB::table('rooms')->select('*'); */
    $rooms = Rooms::join('users', function($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'rooms.user_id');
    })
->select(['rooms.id as room_id', 'rooms.name as room_name', 'rooms.status as room_status', 'rooms.created_at as room_created_at', 'rooms.updated_at as room_updated_at', 'rooms.*', 'users.*', 'property_type.*', 'room_type.*']);
Log::info("returning to view......");
    return DataTables::of($rooms)
        ->make(true);
}
```

*View*

```
<script>
   $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: "{{ url('admin/rooms-list') }}",
           columns: [
                    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    { data: 'host_name', name: 'host_name' },
                    { data: 'property_type', name: 'property_type' },
                    { data: 'status', name: 'status' },
                    { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
                    { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' },
                    { data: 'views_count', name: 'views_count' }
                 ]
        });
     });
  </script>



<table class="table table-bordered" id="laravel_datatable">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>ID</th>
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Host Name</th>
                     <th>Property type</th>
                     <th>status</th>
                     <th>Created at</th>  
                     <th>Updated at</th>
                     <th>Views Count</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
```

**Am getting this error**

[image]

Can someonehelp to sove this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that you're logging in some points of your process. Do all of them get executed?

Comment: yeah logging s printing perfectly